# Printing PDF from JasperReports

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports

I'm new to JasperReports and find myself getting pretty lost with it.  I've got a webapp in JSF that I want to use to print a PDF.  I've built the report, and am able to successfully compile and fill it with all my parameters.  However, I'm lost on the actual output portion.  I'd like it go to a printer as a PDF.  I don't care about ever seeing it on screen, straight to printer would be the ideal (from the server would be ideal, but client would also be fine as we could setup the clients to print as necessary (it's an internal app)).

Comment: The sample: http://helptodeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/02/way-of-printing-jasper-report-at-client.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I'd like it go to a printer as a PDF. I don't care about ever seeing it on screen, straight to printer would be the ideal*

You can't do it with plain HTML/CSS/JS. As JSF is basically just a HTML/CSS/JS code generator, it can't do any magic for you. Closest what you can get is JavaScript's `window.print()`, but that would still show the user the printer settings and such (basically, it does the same as `Ctrl+P`).

Your best bet is to create an [Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) which uses [the `javax.print` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) and then embed that Applet in your JSF page by HTML `<applet>` or `<object>` tag.

If you *can* live with seeing it straight on screen and delegating the print job to the enduser itself, then you can send a PDF file to screen by JSF as follows:

```
public void sendPdf() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"filename.pdf\"");
    yourJasperReportsClass.writePdfTo(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

I have never worked with JasperReports, so the `yourJasperReportsClass.writePdfTo()` was just a random guess, but the hint should be clear enough. You basically need to instruct it to write the PDF to the response body.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, that printer is actually connected to the server, not to the client and you actually want to let the server print it to its printer. In that case, just use [the `javax.print` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html). At the bottom of that document you can find some code examples. Here's an extract of relevance:

> #### Using the API
>
> A typical application using the Java Print Service API performs these steps to process a print request:
>
> - Chooses a DocFlavor.
> - Creates a set of attributes.
> - Locates a print service that can handle the print request as specified by the DocFlavor and the attribute set.
> - Creates a Doc object encapsulating the DocFlavor and the actual print data, which can take many forms including: a Postscript file, a JPEG image, a URL, or plain text.
> - Gets a print job, represented by DocPrintJob, from the print service.
> - Calls the print method of the print job.
>
> The following code sample demonstrates a typical use of the Java Print Service API: locating printers that can print five double-sided copies of a Postscript document on size A4 paper, creating a print job from one of the returned print services, and calling print.
>
> ```
> FileInputStream psStream; 
>
> try { 
>   psStream = new FileInputStream("file.ps");
> } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
> } 
>
> if (psStream == null) { 
>   return;
> }
>
> DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT; 
> Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null); 
> PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
> aset.add(new Copies(5)); 
> aset.add(MediaSize.A4); 
> aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX); 
>
> PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset); > 
> if (services.length > 0) { 
>   DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob(); 
>
>   try {
>     job.print(myDoc, aset); 
>   } catch (PrintException pe) {
>   }
> }
> ```

It's not relevant if the above code called by a JSF managed bean. It's after all just Java. You might only want to modify the `DocFlavor` and other settings.

Comment: I'm not surprised that client-side can't do it, but I can't print from the backend server process either?

Comment: Only if the printer is connected to the webserver.

Comment: Oh well, it's not different from plain Java then. Use `javax.print` API. It's irrelevant if that Java code is inside a JSF managed bean or a plain Java application with `main()`. You can find code example at bottom of API's package summary which I linked in my answer.

Comment: Looks like I should be generating a PDF with "JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrintObject, externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());", however Glassfish is throwing "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response".  This is a void action, so it shouldn't have an Action also trying to generate output that would be interfering?  Doing PDF to screen seems like a good testing step even if I ultimately go straight to printer, so I'm trying your sample from above first!

Comment: Sure that you have `facesContext.responseComplete();` in end of action method? This tells JSF to not handle the response by itself, simply because you've already handled it. Oh, this should also not be done by an ajax request, but a normal request, although I doubt if that would ever throw this kind of exception.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Additionally, you can read this article which describe how to set predefined printer options for report: http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/rss/2007/03/22/Choosing-a-printer-programmatically-in-Jasper-Reports

Comment: Curious (in regards to the PDF via outputStream to display)...  Yes, facesContext.responseComplete() is at the end.  If I remove the exportReportToPdfStream call, then I *don't* get the error (I just get "malformed PDF" in the browser, which is entirely to be expected in that case since it has not been passed any data, just header info).

Comment: To be sure, when that line is present, you get the PDF as expected, but you got the exception in the server log? Or don't you get the PDF in browser window at all, but instead the exception?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I've been doing this for too long today...  Nothing at all, but I see why.  Completely forgot to look at the Glassfish logs.  Jasper is throwing a missing library error, for something I don't recognize and don't see in it's library list.  So, something Jasper related is causing me to crash out before responseComplete, and then the whole house of cards falls down.  :-)  Should be a simple matter of finding the missing library and setting it up!