# Print Jasper Report Using a Printer

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I am creating a report using Jasper report and save it as a pdf file in the drive. I want to get a print out using a printer of that report.
After a brief google search I found there are two ways to do that.
1)open the pdf in the print preview mode and then print
2)send the jasperPrint file directly to the the printer.

Below is the code that I have done so far. Can someone please guide me to do one of the above methods using java in  java web application. Thank you.

```
public int printCashReceipt(){
try{
   Connection connection = util.DatabaseConnection.getDbConnection();
   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../reports/ReceiptCash.jrxml"));

   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("receipt_id", 6);

   JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, connection);

   File outDir = new File("C:/reports");
   outDir.mkdirs();

   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "C:/reports/ReceiptCash.pdf");
   System.out.println("Done!");
   connection.close();

   return 1;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
       return 0;
   }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing PDF from JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999792/printing-pdf-from-jasperreports) & [JasperReport with spring MVC : print report on client side without displaying it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28961181/876298)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jp, parameters, jrBeanDatasource);     
JasperViewer.viewReport(print, true);
```